# Where can I add Form Fields so that they can be sent in Request Payload for POST method, I am inside a React App and using Fetches

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch

Below is the Request Payload, I need to add few other fields present on my Form.

````
comment: ""
ownership: "47"
parts: []
placeIdToRepair: "ABC"
requestCategory: "STD"
requestType: "REP"
returnReason: "3RO"
returnType: "STD" ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Using **fetch API** after extracting your form fields

```
const handleSubmit = event => { /* function passed to onSubmit event on your form */
  event.preventDefault(); /* preventing browser from reloading */
  fetch(/* URL */, {
    method: ”POST",
    headers: {
        ”content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ /* and finally */
        /* form key: form value */
    })
   }}
```

I hope I understood you question